# Django environment variables aren't working

Tags: django

I'm running Django on gcloud Ubuntu 18.04.

Everytime that I try to set environment variable instead of a string i get an error, but when I use echo or os.environ.get() from shell, it works fine.

#### settings.py

```
... #this settings doest work
DB_NAME  = os.environ.get("DB_NAME")
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': DB_NAME,#
        ...
    }
}
...
... #this settings  works fine
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': "Candlelight",
            ...
        }
    }
```

#### from bash

```
  ~/myproject$ echo $DB_NAME
    Candlelight
```

#### from shell

```
 >>> import os
    >>> os.environ.get('DB_NAME')
    'Candlelight'
    >>> 
>>> from core.settings import *
>>> DB_NAME
'Candlelight'
>>>
```

#### .bashrc

```
export DB_NAME = "Candlelight"
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: what user is the env var being set as, and what user is django being run on.  Just because the env vars are visible to your login shell doesn't mean its visible to others

Comment: @Jason i guess both are running on default (same user)

Comment: @AmitHaim does really the error matters i know for a fact if switch the variable to a string it'll just work fine

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you expect actually? I can not see any issue in your question! And what is the error (the question is relevant)? What error does your `settings.py` raise?
In shell it works fine, but not in `settings.py`?

Comment: Are you running django from the shell where it is defined?

Comment: @DanielM apach2 and mod_wsgi

Comment: and did you set  `DB_NAME` on `envvars.sh`?

Comment: @DanielM what is envvars.sh ? i wrote all the settings i have

Comment: `.bashrc` isn't executed when you run using apache/mod_wsgi - usually under `/etc/apache2` you should have `envvars` file with the shell settings you want (no .sh ending)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204953/discussion-between-lelouch-and-daniel-m).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not running django from the same shell that sets the env variable (your user shell runs `.bashrc` but apache does not)

Try adding the environment variable under `/etc/apache2/envvars` and restart apache service.

Then when running django it should see the env-var setting.

Another thing, it is important not to have spaces when setting an environment variable, it should be:

```
export DB_NAME=Candlelight
```

Answer (score 9):

Try to give a default value to the var you are trying to get:

```py
DB_NAME = os.getenv("DB_NAME", "just_a_test")
print(DB_NAME)
```

If `just_a_test` prints, then it means your environment variable is not accessible from your `settings.py`.

I'm not sure of the issue you are facing with (it could be a lot of things, especially when working with `Docker` for instance), but I will share with you how I do manage now `env` variables only useful for one `Django` project. I never encountered any issue with that way to do.

First, install `python-dotenv`:

```sh
pip install python-dotenv
```

Then, create a `.env` file at the root of your project. This file will contain all your useful environment variables you want to use for your project:

```sh
# .env

DB_NAME="Candlelight"
```

Finally, use that var in your `settings.py` (as good practice, **always** attribute a default value to your vars):

```py
# settings.py

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
DB_NAME = os.getenv("DB_NAME", "default_val")
```

Main interests of that way to do:

- you do not pollute the `.bashrc` file (and so the global environment of your session),
- everything relative to your project is located in one single `.env` file, which is easy to ignore if dealing with a `git` repo.
- you don't have to care with `apache2` or `nginx` settings, because `Django` will look anyway for that `.env` file.

To me, that's the best and cleanest way to deal with environment variables for `Django` projects!

Comment: Man, I stopped using python-dotenv since I thought I would just use the `os.environ.get`, but you got me back on it. Thanks

Comment: This isn't useful if you are using environment variables so you don't have passwords hard coded into your source code

Answer (score -1):

LeLouch gave the solution but no one has posted the code or an example. I currently had this issue working with Django 4 and Linux and trying to access system environmental variables.
To use system variables just wrap the str(os.environ.get(secret_key))..
So in the settings file it will look like this..

In the settings.py file:

SECRET_KEY= str(os.environ.get(secrety_key))

you have to use str(os.environ.get()), using str(os.environ['DJANGO_SECRET_KEY']) won't work, or hasn't for me.

Only reason I am answering this is because all the other solutions of creating a file in the same directory as the settings.py file and accessing them that way doesn't make sense. IF someone can access the settings.py file then they can access the configuration file also.. Totally outside the Django system seems to be the best way to go for the environment variables.